# How to Add a Subscribe Button to Your Video, There Is No BRANDING Menu

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-studio

I want to add a `Subscribe Button` to my youtube video.
Youtube had many updates in year 2020.
Please check this video that i followed :
[How to Add a Subscribe Button to Your Video | 2020 YouTube Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThkvNmflr-8)

There is no BRANDING menu in this path :

> YouTube Studio | Settings | Channel | Branding Menu

Where is that menu in YouTube 2020 & How to Add a Subscribe Button to my youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

To add a watermark (in your case the subscribe button), go to:

> YouTube Studio -> Customization -> Branding

then scroll down to 'Video watermark' and select your display time:

> End of video: The video watermark will show for the last 15 seconds of the video.

> Custom start time: The video watermark will begin showing at a time you choose.

> Entire video: The video watermark will show throughout the entire video.

Click CHANGE and select an image (the subscribe button image). Change the size of your image, then click DONE. Click PUBLISH.

Your video watermark must meet the following criteria:

1. Minimum 150x150 pixels.
2. Square image less than 1 MB in size.

Refer the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2972003#zippy=%2Cadd-your-video-watermark) for the detailed steps.